# How to scroll to bottom of tableview?

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

I have to scroll to the bottom of the tableview. In iOS 10 it is working fine and in iOS 11 it scrolls to half of the tableview and stops. It's not scrolling to the bottom of the tableview.

```
[tableObj scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, tableObj.contentSize.height - tableObj.frame.size.height,tableObj.frame.size.width, tableObj.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about try this.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tableDataList.count - 1, section: 0)

table.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: No, It's not working. Not scrolling down to end of the tableview

Comment: NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_dataList.count inSection:0];                                                                                                                 
   

 [tableObj scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

Comment: Oh I think I made a mistake. I forgot minus 1 for tableDataList.count. you must know why minus 1 needed.